# Accessing Stanford Core NLP Coreference Chain output in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use the Stanford Core NLP `:coref_chain` to get a list of entity mentions out of some text. When I run this code:

```
text = 'Angela Merkel met Nicolas Sarkozy on January 25th in ' +
   'Berlin to discuss a new austerity package. Sarkozy ' +
   'looked pleased, but Merkel was dismayed.'

pipeline =  StanfordCoreNLP.load(:tokenize, :ssplit, :pos, :lemma, :parse, :ner, :dcoref)
text = StanfordCoreNLP::Annotation.new(text)
pipeline.annotate(text)

  puts text.get(:coref_chain)
```

I get this output:

```
{1=CHAIN1-["Angela Merkel" in sentence 1, "Merkel" in sentence 2], 3=CHAIN3-["January 25th" in sentence 1], 4=CHAIN4-["Berlin" in sentence 1], 5=CHAIN5-["Nicolas Sarkozy on January 25th" in sentence 1, "Sarkozy" in sentence 2], 6=CHAIN6-["a new austerity package" in sentence 1]}
```

Is this a hash? According to the documentation on Stanford site, I should be able to access these values through the attribute names but no combination has worked for me. In fact, adding anything other than `to_s` yields a "no method found" error.

Does any one know how I would get the names out of this? Just "Angela Merkel" for example? In a best case scenario, I would get the start, end and heads as well.

Comment: Please provide output: **puts text.get(:coref_chain).class.name**, but i suppose it is text ... hash needs to be in format of { key => value }, if you look closer into documentation - sentences are in arrays (tokens).

Comment: but you call coref_chain on text not on the tokens so I'm not sure that works? The output of your suggestion is: Rjb::Rjb_JavaProxy

Comment: Upon further tinkering, it doesn't appear that the coref features work within the Stanford Core NLP gem. Oh well, on to try treat (so far so good for anyone else who comes across this)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the example code for using the gem](https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp). You have to loop over the returned value of `text.get`:

```
text.get(:sentences).each do |sentence|
```

You can loop over the sentences returned and extract further information.

What you think is a Hash isn't a hash. It's a string representation of the internal structure they're using created when you told it to `puts`, similar to what an `inspect` would return.

Comment: looping over the sentences works for things like the basic dependencies but not for coref chain which is at the document level. According to the documentation, there should be attributes returned with the chain and these are the ones i want to access; mentions, head, start index, etc. Whats weird is that at the token level, I can see the tags in which each output is wrapped. With coref_chain, i cannot see these tags in the output. Looking at the documentation gain, if you output an entire xml doc, the tags are there for coreference.